# I cannot from sage.all import *, nor the specific sage packages I'm using

Tags: mkdir, sage

I'm using some of sage's features in a python program I'm writing - mostly sage.groups.free_group and I can't seem to import it properly.
I do have sage installed in my conda env and I am using said conda env to run my script with the proper python binary.
However, I can't seem to be able to make it get past the sage import -

```
  File "/Users/<user_name>/repos/uni/stable_primitivity_rank/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sage.all import Category

  File "/Users/<user_name>/miniconda3/envs/sage/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sage/all.py", line 124, in <module>
    from sage.misc.all       import *         # takes a while

  File "/Users/<user_name>/miniconda3/envs/sage/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sage/misc/all.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .misc import (BackslashOperator,

  File "/Users/<user_name>/miniconda3/envs/sage/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sage/misc/misc.py", line 110, in <module>
    os.makedirs(DOT_SAGE, mode=0o700, exist_ok=True)

  File "/Users/<user_name>/miniconda3/envs/sage/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)

  File "/Users/<user_name>/miniconda3/envs/sage/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

OSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported: '/home/<user_name>'
```

I tried `from sage.all import *`,
`from sage.all import dickman_rho`,
and just `from sage.all import groups`,
`from sage.all import Category`.

I tried running this using `sage --python` and `sage -python`, and through the sage shell.

None of these work - I'm getting some mkdir problem which is quite foolish, but I wasn't able to solve. I would appreciate any help..

Edit: I believe this is somehow related to me using MacOS but still not sure how to solve this.
Also tried to comment out the line /home auto_home -nobrowse,hidefromfinder in the file /etc/auto_master and restarting, didn't work either.

Comment: Do you try to create the `.sage` folder manually (`mkdir -m 700 ~/.sage`), and see if the problem is solved?

Comment: @IvanaGyro I already have a .sage folder in my home dir with 700 permissions. Do you mean remove and create a fresh empty one?

Comment: No. It's fine if the folder exists. Sagemath gets `DOT_SAGE` from your environment variables first and fallback to `~/.sage` if there is no `DOT_SAGE` the in environment variables. What command did you use to run the script? Can you check if `DOT_SAGE` isn't in your environment variables (it doesn't need to be there)?